# Can't join host Hyper-V to guest virtual machine's domain controller

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

Below, is the text of a question from superuser that was never responded to. I can't find any information on this issue and have exactly the same problem.

> I created Domain Controller role running inside a guest operating
>   system on a Hyper-V host server. Tried to add that same Hyper-V host
>   server to the domain of the guest virtual machine that Hyper-V hosts,
>   but I get the following message:
>
> The following error occured attempting to join the domain "mydomain":
>   The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.
>
> It does ask me for username and password if I try to join "mydomain",
>   but joining "mydomain.local" gives an immediate error that says
>   there's no such domain, basically.

The reason I want to join the domain from the host is so that backups peformed from the host can be stored on a domain network share managed by file and storage services.

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/723738/cant-join-host-hyper-v-to-guest-virtual-machines-domain-controller-running-wit) was asked a year ago on superuser, 600+ views, no responses at all. I can't comment there and I don't have an answer so I have decided to post here.

I am not sure how to comply with superuser and serverfault practices here, but hopefully this 'repost' is ok. I hope someone can help with this issue.

Comment: I don't believe the Hyper-V Host can "see" the guest to be able to contact it.

Comment: You should not be using .local in a domain name.

Comment: Davidw - Maybe but then how does one join a host to the domain? I know doing that is a debated practice but I think I want to do it for my small office domain. Does one add the host from the dc?

Comment: Michael - that's what the quote has in it, but I used .lan. I have not had any issues with 'normal' pcs or servers joining the domain. I quoted the year ago post because it was otherwise identical to my issue.

Comment: You shouldn't use any fictitious TLD or domain name.

Comment: A member server has to be able to contact the domain controller to join that domain, and be able to communicate with it.

Comment: Assuming you installed the DNS Server role on the DC and aren't using some other DNS server for your AD DNS zone, is the Hyper-V host using the Domain Controller for DNS? If not then that's your problem.

Comment: MDMarra - I had some exposure to a real tld that was used for a AD domain, causing issues with name resolution. I know it can be worked out, but I'm very new to this and wanted to simplify things. Is any of this focus on the lan name relevant to the question? It may be, and I appreciate any feedback I get on domains. I am just not sure if you 'guys' are correcting a bad practice on principle, or if you're saying it's part of the problem I've presented.

Comment: Any fictitious domain name can screw you up, especially if there is a home/SOHO router around.

Comment: Also, what type of Hyper-V virtual switch did you create for the Domain Controller VM?

Comment: If you couldn't connect to the AD server at all, you woudn't get prompted for a user name and password. There is normally more details Can you post the contents of that

Comment: Have you validated connectivity from the host to the guest (ie: have you verified the host and guest are talking to each other)?. Is the host using the guest for DNS (it will need to)?

Comment: joeqwerty - thank you that was it. It's just the level of issue that I should have been able to resolve on my own, just didn't get there yet. I can't mark your comment as an answer. Is there a way for an admin here to do that? Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: Comments cannot be marked as an answer, it has to be posted as an answer.

Comment: @Drifter104: If the OP attempts to join the domain using the NetBIOS name of the domain, a NetBIOS broadcast will resolve the name, connect to a Domain Controller and will prompt for credentials. The DNS client will then attempt to resolve the FQDN of a Domain Controller and will fail if the client isn't configured to use the DC for DNS. So while you can join a domain using the NetBIOS name you can only do so if the DNS client can also resolve the FQDN of a Domain Controller.

Comment: Yes, but the comments prior were leaning towards connectivity issues and around the name of the domain. This seemed to imply the point I raised had been missed

Comment: @Drifter104: Right. I'm not debating the validity of your point. I was making an additional point.

Comment: Completely didn't get that from your comment. My mistake.

Comment: No worries. Seems I've been getting my wires crossed lately. :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you installed the DNS Server role on the DC and aren't using some other DNS server for your AD DNS zone, is the Hyper-V host using the Domain Controller for DNS? If not then that's probably your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have read many posts but, actually there is a 30 seconds fix for it. I will post a video for this fix as well but, solution is just use only IP v4 address and remove IP v6 check mark from you NIC card properties from domain and all members or from clients willing to join domain. In short, there is an issue only when we use IP v6 and IP v4. Refer to my youtube videos where I will add some new SCCM videos. I have already posted some videos too after fixing this issue on my virtual environment using Hyper-v.
Note: This solution assuems you are using on every client preferred DNS address from you domain i.e. XYZ.com , you are able to ping from client to Dc and from DC to client, network browsing is okay and there is no issue at all but, you cannot join domain. Again, use just only IPV4 address and see the majic. You will be able to join domain with no issue.

Enayat Meer

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to create a INTERNAL SWICTH on your Hyper-V host, then add a network card to your virtual domain controller and assign it an ip to that network card once you ping the ip address of the Hyper-V host from your virtual domain controller you will be able to join the Physical Hyper-V host to your AD network.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem:

Windows Hyper-V Server hosting some virtual machines, one of which was both the DNS Server and the Domain Controller (was a physical server once but then got virtualized). When trying to join the host machine to the domain I'd get the same message as you did:

> The following error occurred attempting to join the domain "DOMAIN_NAME":
>   The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.

Then I checked the host's DNS settings. The Preferred DNS server wasn't pointing to my DNS Server's (a VM) IP address. I changed that and bingo: I was able to join the domain.